# is it possible to write a whole method that returns a value in ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-operator

Is it possible to do this kind of code in the ternary operator in javascript? If yes, I think I'm doing it wrong, when I tried the code below I wrote it just return the whole `function(){}` method

```
let products = [
  {
    price: 2.6,
    quantity: 5,
  },
  {
    price: 5.9,
    quantity: 5,
  },
  {
    price: 2.3,
    quantity: 5,
  },
  {
    price: 4.9,
    quantity: 5,
  }
];

let sumtotal = products.length > 1 ? function(){
  let total = 0;
  for(const { price, quantity } of products) {
    total += (price * quantity);
  }
  return parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
} : function() {
  let total = (products[0].price * products.quantity);
  return parseFloat (total).toFixed(2);
};

console.log(sumtotal);
```

I was hoping that this would return an actual value like the output would be an `Integer` or `float`.

Comment: Your ternary branches evaluate function expressions, so you assign a function to `sumtotal`. Yes, this works. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Can you show where `products` is defined and how `sumtotal` is used?

Comment: @Bergi Oh I see what I did there, I assigned a function to it, I was trying to make the `sumtotal` return an integer or float, the calculated price, when I tried to check it on the console.log(sumtotal) it literally return the function not the value.

Comment: You can use [an IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/1048572) for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I was hoping that this would return an actual value like the output would be an Integer or float."*

You can wrap your function definition in parenthesis and call it with `()` immediately after. An IIFE. You already have `return` so you are good on that part.

WITH CHANGES:

```
  let sumtotal = products.length > 1 ? (function(){
    let total = 0;
    for(const { price, quantity } of products) {
      total += (price * quantity);
    }
    return parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
  })() : (function() {
    let total = (products[0].price * products.quantity);
    return parseFloat (total).toFixed(2);
  })();
```

With the IIFEs in place, the functions will run where they are. I haven't checked any other parts of your code, so this solution is just for the "return an actual value like the output would be an Integer or float" part.

Comment: Great, it works! r/todayilearned/ hahaha, thanks!